# border-color and border-left-width ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I am tryng to write code for "**diagonal border**". 
If I use `border-color:transparent` in IE, it doesn't work, but if I use `border-color:#000000` its works fine.
In other browser (chrome, firefox it) works

I must use transparent for my website, and at this link there is an example
**http://jsfiddle.net/K2EGY/5/**

```
<style>
body { margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;  }
.init{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}    
#triangle-bottomright {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-color: transparent #bccdd7  transparent;
    border-style: solid solid solid dashed;
    border-width: 0 0 250px 0px;    
}
#triangle-bottomright-2 {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-color: transparent #bccdd7  #000000;
    border-style: solid solid solid dashed;
    border-width: 0 0 250px 0;  
}
</style>
```

**JS** and **HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //DIV TRIANGOLARI
    $(window).on('resize', function(e){
        var w = $( window ).width();
        $('#triangle-bottomright').css('border-left-width', w+'px');
        $('#triangle-bottomright-2').css('border-left-width', w+'px');      
    })
    $(window).trigger( "resize" )   
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="init"></div>
    <div id="triangle-bottomright"></div>
    <div class="init"></div>
    <div id="triangle-bottomright-2"></div>    
</body>
```

PS. I need solution for ie 10 and ie 11, but if it works also in ie9 it's better

Comment: What version of IE you need? If is IE9 or greater perhaps you could try rgba(0,0,0,0).

Comment: I have only IE10 and IE11..and it doesn't work rgba(0,0,0,0).

Comment: You should update your question specifying which versions of IE you need the solution to be working with

Comment: I need solution for ie 10 and ie 11, but if it works also in ie9 it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alpha channel:

```
border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
```

The "a", or alpha, is a 0-1 value that represents opacity (0 being transparent and 1 being completely opaque).

Hope this helps!